# Lock keyboard until key input

Tags: powershell, keyboard, locking

I'm a bit new to scripting in power shell (not essentially new but haven't gotten around to play much with it recently). Anyway, straight to the point, I would like to create a script that locks the keyboard only (not the screen) until a specific set of keys is pressed, or a password is input, either way tbh.

Thing is, I have only found references that disable the keyboard completely, so I can't seem to get around with this.

Is it even possible to lock the keyboard until a key chord is pressed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the goal/purpose? On a Windows machine, you can press `Windows+L` to lock the computer.

Comment: The purpose is to keep displaying the information on screen that is streamed to a TV without allowing any input from the keyboard

Comment: think the user32.dll function disable-userinput + a loop + a method of getting keyboard messages that are sent to windows API to check for string that you

Comment: Won't that disable the keyboard completely and therefore block any input? @learnAsWeGo

Comment: There are a handful of seemingly simply utilities that handle this as well. Steps outside the bounds of the question but its worth considering. https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11570/disable-the-keyboard-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-windows/

Comment: Can't use any third party application due to work restrictions :P (That's why I'm recurring to powershell)

Comment: Why not just disconnect the keyboard?

Comment: It's a laptop, haha

Comment: Use a desktop, or connect an external monitor and restrict access to the laptop itself.

Comment: That goes beyond me, the laptop is on a locked position on a wall, right next to the TV.

I don't have the power to order a desktop or else. Haha.

Comment: Perhaps setting up as a kiosk would be useful. Beyond that, a software-only solution is not going to be hard to bypass, particularly if people have direct physical access to the computer. I think your question is really outside the scope of what we can offer on stackoverflow.

Comment: Oh well, I was just wondering if there was a way to lock the keyboard trough powershell instead of disabling it entirely.

But thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 0):

Using the System.Console class and the ReadKey() Object, you can get the key that is pressed in the keyboard. 
 An example I have a loop that will continue executing until y or n is pressed from the keyboard. Hope it solves your problem

```
 do 
{
    $key = [Console]::ReadKey($true)
    $value = $key.KeyChar

    switch($value) {
        y { Write-Host "Do something"}
        n { Write-Host "Do something else" }
    }
}
while ($value -notmatch 'y|n')
```

Comment: this only stops keyboard input into powershell application itself

Comment: It's a good tip but not quite, although thank you.

What I need is to know how to *Lock* the keyboard until a certain key group is pressed, but I don't know how to lock the keyboard without disabling it.

Do you happen to know if it's even possible? :P

Comment: key group ? means number row or text row ? something like that ?

Comment: As in a Key Chord like Ctrl + Shift + 7